# R function to match column names and automatically tabulate correlations

Tags: r

Let's say I have a data frame:

```
library(psych)
x.1 <- acs(1, 3, 5)
y.1 <- acs(2, 6, 8)
x.2 <- acs(2, 3, 4)
y.2 <- acs(5, 10, 15)
df <- data.frame(x.1, y.1, x.2, y.2)
```

I'm trying to create a function that will do three things...

1. Match the first character of the column name (x or y) with all other variables sharing that first character but not the last (1 or 2)
2. Compute correlations between these variables
3. Tabulate the correlations in a simple two column table that lists variable in the first column and correlation in the second

This is what I came up with but unable to find a way to take it further.

```
    FS.function <- function(x) {

  colnames <- colnames(x)

  for i in colnames[x] {

    if (substring(colnames[i], 1, 2) == substring(colnames[i], 1, 2) & str_sub(colnames[i], -1, -1) != str_sub(colnames[i], -1, -1) {

      var1 <- colnames(x)[i]
      r <- corr.test(X1, X2)

    }
  }
```

Comment: Your data.frame contains no numbers which one could use to calculate a correlation. Is there a specific reason for having a data.frame like this?

Comment: My mistake - acs was not needed and is only ever needed for character input. As pointed out by jayke, I should have used c() to create numeric vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need the acs(). Maybe you were looking for c() to create a vector?
Anyway, this might put you on your way:

```
FS = function(df) {
  first_letter_shortlist = unique(substr(names(df),1,1))
  result = list()

  for (letter in first_letter_shortlist) {
    regexp = paste0("^", letter)
    cn = grep(pattern = regexp, x = names(df))
    result[[letter]] = cor(df[,cn])
  }
  return(result)
}
```

This will also give you correlations if more than 2 columns start with the same letter.

To test it try:

```
x.1 <- c(1, 3, 5)
y.1 <- c(2, 6, 8)
x.2 <- c(2, 3, 4)
y.2 <- c(5, 10, 15)
df <- data.frame(x.1, y.1, x.2, y.2)

FS(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there might be more than 2 variables per group I added another x. 
To omit redundancy in the result all values in the upper triangle and on the diagonal of the correlation matrix were set to `NA` and later removed.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
x.1 <- rnorm(100)
x.2 <- rnorm(100) + 0.7 * x.1
x.3 <- rnorm(100)
y.1 <- rnorm(100)
y.2 <- rnorm(100)
df <- data.frame(x.1, y.1, x.2, y.2, x.3)

groups   <- split(names(df), substring(names(df), 1,1))
cor_list <- lapply(groups, function(x) { 
                     cm <- data.frame(cor(df[ ,x]))
                     cm[upper.tri(cm, diag = TRUE)] <- NA
                     cm %>% rownames_to_column("var1")%>% 
                     gather("var2", "correlation", -var1)}) %>% 
  bind_rows %>% na.omit

 cor_list
 #     var1 var2 correlation
 # 2   x.2  x.1  0.54815545
 # 3   x.3  x.1  0.01838219
 # 6   x.3  x.2 -0.03133936
 # 11  y.2  y.1  0.02388991
```